# ssh_exchange_identification issue raising when trying to install Homebrew in my macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: objective-c, macos, terminal, homebrew

I have searched many answers. But, none of them solved my issues.

I have tried to install `homebrew` via terminal, by using `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Following error received:

**Attempt 1:**

```
Donal-Mac-mini:~ mymac$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master --tags --force
Donal-Mac-mini:~ mymac$
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
Donal-Mac-mini:~ mymac$ git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
Cloning into 'homebrew'...
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Donal-Mac-mini:~ mymac$
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed with the help of [these link](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/).

By Adding, SSH keys to my GitHub account and tried to install `Homebrew`. 
Successfully installed.

Following steps:

Generate Key to your GitHub Account:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "yourusername@github.com"
```

Password:

```
It will ask minimum 5 chars password
```

To Check PORT:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Add Generated Key to Git:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Copy that Key:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

PASTE IN SSH KEYS under SETTINGS in YOUR GITHUB ACC:

[image]

Next in Terminal,

```
ssh -T git@github.com

Hi yourusername! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Start to Install Homebrew.